# Number of min clusters to set in hcpc function within FactoMineR

Tags: r, clustering

I am doing MCA prior to clustering (both using FactoMineR package). I was wondering if there is any possible way to determine the min number of clusters to set in the [code](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FactoMineR/versions/2.4/topics/HCPC)?